# How to build big applications

Tags: famo.us

I'm wondering how to structure my application. Should I use custom views and one main view that will control them. Or is it better to hold my views in a lightbox. All of the examples I've found are somehow limited of functionality and present a single or a few screens. What is the right way to organize a bigger application?

Comment: A question must be more specific. this type of question should be discussed on related forums.

Comment: I can't imagine more specific question than that. You can contribute with personal practices, examples, links and etc.

Comment: Are you asking us to send you our big projects for you?

Comment: No I'm asking to explain how you build it

Comment: There is no correct answer, there are many ways to go about it, and depends on what other tech you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I'm wondering too.

Starting point:

- Famo.us apps are structured in a hierarchical rendering tree.
- Famo.us uses RequireJS modules.
- Famo.us encourages the use of **Views**

  - Views are reusable components.
  - Views encapsulate functionality (and part of the rendering tree).
  - Views communicate using **events**.
  - View get initialized by an **options** object.

We need to add structure to manage:

- Business logic
- Non-UI functionality like REST api calls, audio, local storage, etc.
- Data-flow:

  - Update data on user input
  - Update view on data change

### Modules, events and loose coupling

Goals:

- Scalable application structure.
- Small, independent, testable modules.
- Promote re-use of code.
- Easy sharing of modules (just drop a file your project)
- **No dependence** on other Javascript frameworks.

All to often, there is tight coupling between modules:

- Module instantiates and keeps a reference to another module
- Modules cross their semantic boundries

  - A view that knows about a specific REST api
  - A view that uses specific model code such as Backbone (see Taasky example)

Here is to how to avoid this:

1. Modules emit events when something interesting happens (user input, data change, etc)
2. A **Mediator** listens to the event
3. The Mediator calls the public API of another module.

So, instead of having a View-module know about Backbone model stuff, it emits an user input event like this:

1. Todo-Edit-View emits "User input" event: `"todo-update",{id:1,title:'Code'}`
2. Todo-Mediator listens to the event.
3. Todo-Mediator calls `tasks.find({id:1}).update({title:'Code'})` of Todo module (e.g. using Backbone)

Rules

- There are Modules and Mediators
- Modules have a public API and emit events
- The API and events stay in their semantic boundries; i.e. "updateTitle()" instead of "onBackboneModelChange()"
- The Mediator couples the app, i.e. a backbone model change to a todo-item title update.
- Mediators are singletons
- An application can have multiple mediators.

For example, an e-mail application like GMail could have mediators for

- chat function
- todo list function
- reading e-mail
- writing & sending e-mail

### File structure:

```
/src
   /lib
   /services
   /mediators
   /layout
   /content
   /config
   /main.js
```

Types of modules:

- **Service**: An independent module to encapsulate non-UI functions such as: LocalStorage, Ajax, Web Audio, etc.
- **Layout**: Layout, animation and positioning of content, e.g: ScrollView, HeaderFooterView, etc
- **Content**: Actual content of the app: leaf nodes (surfaces) of the rendering tree.

Note the distinction between **Layout** and **Content**. By seperating UI-components & layout from actual content, it becomes easy to reuse UI patterns such as side-panels, popups, navigation-bars, sticky-headers, scroll-views, etc.

Also, I would recommend creating a `*.css` for every **Layout** containing only **structure** and minimal theming. All theming can be overriden/extended in `config/theme.css`, so it's easy to reskin an app.

Other code:

- **Mediator**: Couples modules using events and public APIs.
- **Config**: Contains all options used throughout the app on initialization.
- **main.js**: Bootstraps the app.

### Bootstrap app in Main.js

1. Create mediators
2. Create services
3. Construct rendering tree

### Module life-cycle

- A module **must** be contained in a single file, i.e. **don't** depend on external libraries!

When a module is created, it announces its presence to all mediators. We use the Famo.us `Engine` to emit a global event. This will be the **only** required dependency!

```
 Engine.trigger('created',this)
```

When a module is destroyed, it announces its destruction to all mediators.

```
 Engine.trigger('destroyed',this)
```

The mediator listens to `created` and `destroyed` events and glues modules together:

```
 var someDataModule; // Backbone or whatever
 Engine.on('create',function(module){
    if(module instance of SomeDataModule) {
        var someDataModule = module;
    }
    if(module instanceof TodoView) {
      module.on('change-title',function({id:id,title:title}){
          someDataModule.find({id:id}).set('title',title);
      })
    }
 })
```

In simple mediators, you can initialiaze modules in order (i.e `SomeDataModule` before `TodoView`). However, in more complex scenarious, you might need to use a `Promise` to couple everything.

### Note on dependencies

There are three exceptions on "self-contained" modules:

1. **Layout** and **Content** modules are allowed to have hierachical dependencies. Parents can initialize children, and expect certain events from these children. A `ListView` might initialize `ItemView` and handle `ItemRemoved` events.
2. **Services** can be a Facade/Adapter for another service. For example, a `DataService` might provide an simplification, abstraction and security layer for a `RestApiService`.
3. Of course, mediators have hard-wired dependencies because they couple the app!

Answer (score 1):

Famo.us is focused on UI, so you better look for a MVC pattern to have better structure, specially on large projects, actually as Famo.us is very young it only have an integration with Angular:

http://famo.us/integrations/angular/

But is well known that they will add other MVC integrations in the near future

Try Angular and look if it is what you need, it´s a pretty nice MVC Framework, my recommendation is to first learn Angular at least basics (http://angularjs.org/ and then after Famo.us University (http://famo.us/university) you can understand this integration

Comment: There is also an unofficial Meteor integration:

http://famous-components.meteor.com/

(Authored by me, supported by the community)